# PHP Merge inner keys of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to merge inner keys of a php array. There may be some instances of the loop that creates this array where the same key is generated in a different iteration of the loop.

I'm using this method to create my big array:

```
foreach ( $repeater as $file ) : if ($file) :
    loop stuff here;
    $fileArray[$parentCat][$fileCategoryName][] = $theFile;
endif; endforeach;

$postFiles[] = $fileArray; // inside a bigger loop to collect all data
```

I'm trying to merge the **$parentCat** of the array building process.

Example of result array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Category Name] => Array (
            [Sub Category] => Array (
                'fieldvalue' => 'fieldvalue',
            ),
        ),   
    ),
    [1] => Array (
        [Category Name] => Array (
            [Different Sub Category] => Array (
                'differentfieldvalue' => 'differentfieldvalue',
            ),
        ),   
    ),      
),
```

I want to merge the Category Name so that it looks something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Category Name] => Array (
            [Sub Category] => Array (
                'fieldvalue' => 'fieldvalue',
            ),
            [Different Sub Category] => Array (
                'differentfieldvalue' => 'differentfieldvalue',
            ),
        ),   
    ),     
),
```

I've tried using array_merge_recursive, array_merge, and a few other ways with no success. I'm thinking it's something simple that I'm over looking.

Comment: You should solve it by using foreach loop. Have you already tried it?

Comment: I had tried to merge them with a foreach loop afterwards without success. I marked Alexandre's answer below correct as it solved the issue - and quite simply thankfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_merge_recursive` is the right way to go. But you can't call it with an array of arrays, you need to call it with a list of arrays.

Try the following, that should solve your problem:

```
$mergedPostFiles = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $postFiles);
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thank you so much. I had never even seen 'call_user_func_array' function before.

Comment: This is a function that calls a callback. There's a whole set of function in PHP that offer you different ways to manipulate existing functions. `call_user_func_array` is particularly useful when you want to use an array as a list of parameters. Have a look at these: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php